# what is the query of sql database connection

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I want to connect my C# project with SQL database.
which query I have to follow??

```
using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) {
    connection.Open();
}
```

i use this, it is not working

Comment: Figure out your connection string. See http://www.connectionstrings.com/

Comment: define "it is not working". What happens?

Comment: what does not work exactly?

Comment: There is nothing here that we can help you with. And by the way, where is the query? I don't see any

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
namespace Town
{
    class clsconnection
    {
        string connection = @"Data Source=server name;Initial Catalog=databasename;Integrated Security=True";

        public SqlConnection getconnection()
        {
            SqlConnection sql = new SqlConnection(connection);
            sql.Open();
            return sql;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanx, it is working,
i have connect my form with database sucessfully